# The change is not committed in a specific table on database after save change in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In this code i change `IsMale` field of `Table1` and `Name` field of `Table2`.

The change in `Table1` is applied but the change in `Table2` is not applied. `context.SaveChanges()` return `2` but `Table2` is not updated in database
Please help me.

```
using (var context = new ctxdB())
{
    var tbl1 = context.Table1.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Token == token);
    var tbl2 = context.Table2.Find(id);

    tbl1.IsMale = true;
    tbl2.Name = "New name";

    context.Entry(tbl1).State = EntityState.Modified;
    context.Entry(tbl2).State = EntityState.Modified;

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Is the `Find` on table2  finding anything?

Comment: @Locke125, yes of course.

Comment: btw, on the entity you retrieve with FirstOrDefault(), you shouldn't have to manually set the entity state.

Comment: EF context automatically keeps track of the object so it knows which was modified. So I think you don't really need to set the State to EntityState.Modified. Also the SaveChanges() method has an integer return value which indicated how many row was affected during the save. What is the return value?

Comment: @Major context.SaveChanges() return 2 but `Table2` is not updated in database.

Comment: @msitworld Ok it means 2 rows were effected during the save. So it should work fine. First I think you should change the `Find(id)` to  `FristOrDefault(x => x. Id == id)`. If still does not work, try this:
`context.Entry(tbl2).Property(e => e.Name).IsModified = true;`

Comment: @Major Thanks. It was been solved.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the entry here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418(v=vs.113).aspx

It says

> "Finds an entity with the given primary key values. If an entity with the given primary key values exists in the context, then it is returned immediately without making a request to the store. Otherwise, a request is made to the store for an entity with the given primary key values and this entity, if found, is attached to the context and returned."

This tells me that it might be returning an unconnected entity.  You might try calling the `Attach()` method on that entity off of `Context.Table2`.

```
context.Table2.Attach(tbl2);
```

Is there any reason you aren't using `FirstOrDefault()` on that entity set as well?  That should generate a query and attach the model to the entity set.

Comment: Then take the other guy's advice, print out the return number from SaveChanges(), or you can try var tbl2 = context.Table2.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == id);

Comment: context.SaveChanges() return 2 but `Table2` is not updated in database.